# What to change in my app (no AD within it) to avoid violation of the YouTube API Terms of Service?

Tags: android, youtube-api, youtube-data-api

I have a basic app for kids that allows them to click on icon to perform a youtube search ([link to amazon app store](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B011J7PIFE)).

Although I have done a lot of changes in the app, its removed from the Google Play store for "violation of the YouTube Terms of Service or YouTube API Terms of Service" (the full text is attached below).

I did a research here and it seems that my app dosen't have the problems that i have seen in other applications. the app dosen't have AD's and i think its not interfiring to the youtube Ad's and not playing videos in background.

In addition, I filed an appeal to Google Play. Their response was that my app streams copyrighted content from YouTube. I had a search for cartoons, so i removed it and resubmited and the app rejected again for the same reason. 
when i asked for further assistance they answer: "Unfortunately, as much as we'd like to help, we aren't able to provide additional information for your inquiry".Very frustrating.

I'd appreciate your help. Perhaps i made a mistake in the code that implements the YoutubePlayer, Other ideas are welcome to.

**the full Notification from Google Play:**

This is a notification that your application, KidoTube, for package ID com.elelad.kidstube, has been removed from Google Play.

Please address the issue described below and submit a compliant update. Once approved, your application will again be available with all installs, ratings and reviews intact.

REASON FOR REMOVAL:Violation of section 4.4 of the Developer Distribution Agreement.

After a regular review, we have determined that your app downloads, monetizes, or otherwise accesses YouTube videos in violation of the YouTube Terms of Service or YouTube API Terms of Service. Accessing content, a product, or service in an unauthorized manner is a violation of the Developer Distribution Agreement, and is not allowed on Google Play.

All removals are tracked. Repeated removals will result in app suspension, at which point this app will count as a strike against the good standing of your developer account and no longer be available on Google Play.

This notification also serves as notice for other apps in your catalog. You can avoid future removals and/or app suspensions by immediately ensuring that no other apps in your catalog are in violation of (but not limited to) the above policy. Before publishing applications, please ensure your apps’ compliance with the Developer Distribution Agreement and Content Policy.

If you feel we have made this determination in error, you can visit this Google Play Help Center article.

The Google Play Team

**My YoutubeActivity Class:**

```
public class YoutubeActivity extends YouTubeBaseActivity implements YouTubePlayer.OnInitializedListener {

private final static String TAG = YoutubeActivity.class.getSimpleName();
YouTubePlayer player;
public static String YOUTUBE_VIDEO_ID = null;
LayoutInflater mLayoutInflater;
private FragmentActivity myContext;
public TextView textToast;
public View toastLayout;
ProgressBar cycleProgressBar;
Search search = new Search();
List<Video> mVideoList;
private static boolean initialize = false;
GetRandomInBackground getRandomInBackground;
YouTubePlayerView youTubePlayer;
ImageView waitLogo;
AnimationDrawable frameAnimation2;
ImageButton play;


public static void setYoutubeVideoId(String youtubeVideoId) {
    YOUTUBE_VIDEO_ID = youtubeVideoId;
}


@Override
public void onWindowFocusChanged(boolean hasFocus) {
    super.onWindowFocusChanged(hasFocus);
    if (hasFocus) {
        getWindow().getDecorView().setSystemUiVisibility(
                View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_STABLE
                        | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_HIDE_NAVIGATION
                        | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_FULLSCREEN
                        | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_HIDE_NAVIGATION
                        | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_FULLSCREEN
                        | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_IMMERSIVE_STICKY);}
}

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanseState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanseState);
    ContentResolver mContentResolver = getContentResolver();
    setContentView(R.layout.youtube_player);
    waitLogo = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.player_logo);
    play = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.play);
    try {
        startLogoAnimation();
    }catch (Exception e){
        waitLogo.setImageResource(R.mipmap.kidotube);
    }
            youTubePlayer = (YouTubePlayerView) findViewById(R.id.vYouTubePlayer);
    if (Setting.isStartRandomVideo()) {
        getRandomInBackground = new GetRandomInBackground();
        getRandomInBackground.execute();
    }
    youTubePlayer.initialize(Search.getGoogleApiKey(), this);
    youTubePlayer.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
}

@Override
protected void onPause() {
    super.onPause();
    BaseActivity.myLifecycleHandler.onActivityPaused(this);
}

@Override
protected void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    BaseActivity.myLifecycleHandler.onActivityResumed(this);
}

@Override
public void onInitializationFailure(YouTubePlayer.Provider provider,
                                    YouTubeInitializationResult result) {
    Toast.makeText(this, "Cant initialize YouTube Player", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    finish();
}


@Override
public void onInitializationSuccess(YouTubePlayer.Provider provider, YouTubePlayer mplayer,
                                    boolean wasRestored) {
    this.player = mplayer;
    player.setPlayerStyle(YouTubePlayer.PlayerStyle.CHROMELESS);
    player.setPlayerStateChangeListener(playerStateChanageListener);
    player.setPlaybackEventListener(playBackEvaentListener);
    if (!Setting.isStartRandomVideo()) {
        player.loadVideo(YOUTUBE_VIDEO_ID);
    }

}

private YouTubePlayer.PlaybackEventListener playBackEvaentListener = new YouTubePlayer.PlaybackEventListener() {

    public void onBuffering(boolean arg0) {
        Log.v(TAG, "onBuffering");
    }

    @Override
    public void onPaused() {
        Log.v(TAG, "onPaused");
    }

    @Override
    public void onPlaying() {
        Log.v(TAG, "onPlaying");

    }

    @Override
    public void onSeekTo(int arg0) {
        Log.v(TAG, "onSeekTo");
    }

    @Override
    public void onStopped() {
        Log.v(TAG, "onStopped");
    }

};

private YouTubePlayer.PlayerStateChangeListener playerStateChanageListener = new YouTubePlayer.PlayerStateChangeListener() {
    @Override
    public void onAdStarted() {
    }

    @Override
    public void onError(YouTubePlayer.ErrorReason arg0) {
        Log.v(TAG, "onError" );
        Toast.makeText(YoutubeActivity.this, getString(R.string.Video_Error), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        finish();
    }

    @Override
    public void onLoaded(String arg0) {
        Log.v(TAG, "onLoaded" + arg0);
    }

    @Override
    public void onLoading() {
        Log.v(TAG, "onLoading" );
    }

    @Override
    public void onVideoEnded() {
        Log.v(TAG, "onVideoEnded" );
        finish();
    }

    @Override
    public void onVideoStarted() {
        Log.v(TAG, "onVideoStarted");
        play.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
        waitLogo.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
        frameAnimation2.stop();
        youTubePlayer.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    }

};

public class GetRandomInBackground extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {


    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {
        search.SearchNow(MainActivity.getSearchFor());
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Void aVoid) {
        super.onPostExecute(aVoid);
        try {
            if (search.getVideoList() == null || search.getVideoList().size() == 0) {
                Toast.makeText(YoutubeActivity.this, getString(R.string.No_results_found), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                Intent intent = new Intent(YoutubeActivity.this, MainActivity.class);
                startActivity(intent);
            } else {
                mVideoList = search.getVideoList();
                setYoutubeVideoId(search.playRand(mVideoList));
                player.loadVideo(YOUTUBE_VIDEO_ID);
                Search.setNumberOfVideosReturned(20);
            }
        }catch (Exception e){
            finish();
        }
    }
}

public void startLogoAnimation(){
    waitLogo.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.wait_icon);
    frameAnimation2 = (AnimationDrawable) waitLogo
            .getBackground();
    frameAnimation2.start();
}

public int animationDuration(AnimationDrawable animationDrawable){
    int duration = 0;
    int frames = animationDrawable.getNumberOfFrames();
    for (int i = 0; i<frames; i++){
        duration = duration + animationDrawable.getDuration(i);
    }
    return duration;
}
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

well, it was one of my settings. 
I made an option to click on icon and play a random video, apparently it's violation of the API terms. 
When I removed the option the application is approved.

I hope this is the end..